# Slow Performance of MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query which has started running VERY slow now that there are lots of records in the database.

Can anyone see if I can amend the code to improve the performance?

```
    select 
    invoice.id,
    invoice.job_no,
    invoice.invoice_no,
    invoice.invoice_date,
    invoice.invoice_sent,
    invoice.address,
    invoice.contact_id,
    invoice.employee_id,
    invoice.amount as inv_amt,
    sum(job_additions.amount) as add_amt
from
    invoice
        left join
    job_additions ON invoice.invoice_no = job_additions.invoice_no
where
    invoice_sent like '%$_GET[invoice_sent]'
        and job_no like '$_GET[job_no]%'
        and invoice.invoice_no like '$_GET[invoice_no]%'
        and invoice.address like '%$_GET[address]%'
group by invoice.invoice_no
order by invoice.id desc
limit $records_to_return
```

Many thanks,

John

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have amended the code to include the variables that are being passed from a form. Thanks

Comment: '% cannot use an index so will always be slow. Also, your database lacks normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry didn't know about like not using indexes. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: LIKE can use an index - e.g. `LIKE 'x%'`. `LIKE '%x'` cannot use an index.

Comment: You're using a table scan everywhere. 

I'm assuming invoice sent is a boolean, use that. 
invoice no and job no are IDs, use integers for those. Try the same query but without the like statements. You should see a massive improvement. Also, please protect against SQL injection. You're wide open.

Comment: Can you provide some more information, like the type of the values. Your defined indices are interesting as well.

Comment: @JohnHiggins . . . You might want a full text index.  Or, perhaps you can just get rid of the `LIKE` for some of the cases.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have just completely removed the WHERE statement so therefore removed all the LIKES and it's still just as slow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry indicated, a LIKE with a LEADING % to the string can NOT utilize an index.  So, that said, and looking at your query, your performance CAN be improved if you have a multiple field index on those columns without the leading %.

```
 invoice_sent like '%$_GET[invoice_sent]'
        and job_no like '$_GET[job_no]%'
        and invoice.invoice_no like '$_GET[invoice_no]%'
        and invoice.address like '%$_GET[address]%'

index on...  ( Invoice_No, Job_No, ID )
```

I added the "ID" as that is a basis of your ORDER BY clause and could help that optimization too.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the WHERE statement that was slowing it down it was the JOIN. I removed this and it's now blazing fast.

Just need to work out how to achieve the join a better way.